# Windows CF_DIB to CF_BITMAP in clipboard

Tags: windows, bitmap, clipboard

I have no practice with windows programming at all, but now I have a problem I want to fix in some program. I need to place an image to windows clipboard and I have raw pointer to valid `DIB` (device independent bitmap)(in my experiments the dib header version is 3). The program uses the model with delayed clipboard rendering, which means that at first we use `SetClipboardData(CF_DIB, NULL)` and then on `WM_RENDERFORMAT` message the program place the actual data to clipboard with `SetClipboardData(format, dibDataPointer)`.
When I open `clipbrd.exe` (on windows xp) and I choose the `DIB` view, I can see an Image without any problem. But in `msdn` is written that the system can render automatically from `CF_DIB` to `CF_BITMAP` format. I think that's why when I look in `clipbrd.exe` I see 2 formats: `DIB` and `BITMAP`. When I select in `clipbrd.exe` the `bitmap` format I got an error. At first when I looked at the code I saw that there is no case for `CF_BITMAP` in system message handler function, so when system asks to render `CF_BITMAP` nothing valid is placed to clipboard, so I added something like this:

```
switch(format){
case CF_DIB:
case CF_BITMAP: //new code

    if(format == CF_BITMAP)//new cOde
        format = CF_DIB;// new code
....
    SetClipboardData(format, dibDataPointer);
....
```

and hope (actually, I knew that won't gonna work, but gave this way a try) that the system will recognize that I'm going to give as a response for `CF_BITMAP` a `DIB` data and the system will convert in automatically.
So how can I place proper data for `WM_RENDERFORMAT` message with `CF_BITMAP` format from the system if I have a `DIB` data (generally it would be better if I could use the system ability to convert `DIB` to `BITMAP` rather then create `BITMAP` from `DIB` manually)?

Comment: Clipboard formats are a mine field.  But I'm fairly sure that nothing is automatic here and CF_DIB is very different from CF_BITMAP.  Programs publish data on the clipboard in multiple formats to increase the odds that a consuming program supports one of them.  You get the format is likes as the WPARAM in the WM_RENDERFORMAT message.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes you are right about the odds. And that is why I wanted to place СF_BITMAP on the clipboard too. Actually for my purposes I found that the programs I want paste pictures (Wordpad for example) want a DIB with v1 header and positive Y coordinate. Actually v3 header is reverse compatible with v1 header and negative Y coordinate is absolutely valid header value. So I'm really disappointed again in Windows, according that system Wordpad can't work with absolutely valid DIB images. =( But still just for interest I leave the question opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

So I found how to fix the issue. At first it's needed to register for delayed rendering `only` the `CF_DIB` with `SetClipboardData(CF_DIB, NULL)`. The `CF_BITMAP` format will be added to the available clipboard types by `Windows` automatically. Then you need to pass the `dib` data with header of the first version which is described by `BITMAPINFOHEADER` (I have v3 version, I doubt that v4 and v5 headers are going to work) structure with positive `biHeight` (Y Coordinate) on `WM_RENDERFORMAT` with `CF_DIB` format required (the system won't ask you for `CF_BITMAP` because you didn't register it manually). And in this particular case the system will convert `CF_DIB` to `CF_BITMAP` automatically. I don't know will this work with any of the compression method for bitmap data, because I've tested only the `BI_RGB` uncompressed images.

Every other version of `bitmapinfo` `dib` header is reverse compatible with `BITMAPINFOHEADER` and can be successfully copied with `memcpy`. But don't forget to set `biSize` to `sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)`. The second part is to setup positive `Y` coordinate. (I really hope that `DIB` format with compressed data should always have positive height.) But for uncompressed bitmaps `biHeight` can be less then zero, and should be made to a positive value. This will cause the image to be upside down, so it's needed to reverse image rows. The mention should be made that the rows are aligned by 4 bytes.

And the worst thing is that all this standards for headers are described in `microsoft` documentation. But. for example, `Paint` can get the `dib` info v3 header with negative height value, the `clipbrd.exe` can get v3 header with positive height. The `wordpad` wants only v1 header with positive height. And the windows converts `DIB` ro `BITMAP` only with v1 header and positive height. This all are applications which are distributed with `windows` (no `clipbrd.exe` in Vista or later). This is a terrible hell. I hope there won't be any more programming for `Windows` in my entire life.